# Why videoview width size is half?

Tags: swift, camera

Run cameraApp in xcode, Width size is not full

cameraview is not full on uiview.

please help me T_T

also I can't speak english well so ask question very difficult

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    stillImageOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080

    let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

    do {
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)

        if (captureSession.canAddInput(input)) {
            captureSession.addInput(input)

            if (captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput)) {
                captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
                captureSession.startRunning()

                previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
                previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait

                cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)


                previewLayer?.position = CGPoint(x: self.cameraView.frame.width/2, y: self.cameraView.frame.height/2)
                previewLayer?.bounds = cameraView.bounds
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I use your code and add the `previewLayer` to my main view, I get a full size camera view in portrait but a half-size camera view in landscape.

So, the isuse might be in how you have set up the `cameraView`, or it could be something else. I can't be certain. Check the size and bounds of your `cameraView` to see how it is set up.

Also, the `videoGravity` property for `previewLayer` controls how the preview is displayed. You have it set to `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect` which will fit the video within the layer's bounds. If the `cameraView` is set correctly, hou can try a different setting like `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill` to see if that would give you the result you want.